# performSegueWithIdentifier not working for programmatically generated UIButtons (iOS/Swift)

Tags: swift

Xcode 6, Swift, iOS8

I have a view controller that is populated by dynamically generated UIButtons. The number of buttons is dependent on a data feed, and is not static. I count the number of objects in the feed and generate a button for each object. Each button is supposed to segue into a details view that displays the information for its corresponding object.

In the Interface Builder I have created a segue between the two View Controllers and named it. I have not added an IBAction to initiate the segue as I cannot tie it to a specific button.

Inside the View Controller Class I execute the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var localScrollView: UIScrollView! 


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//Define the button dimensions
    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 200
    let buttonHeight:CGFloat = 113

    var xPos:CGFloat = 0
    var scrollViewContent:CGFloat = 0
    var thumbURL:String

//keeps track of the number of videos. The count is used to set a tag on the button to help identify it.
    var vidCount:Int = 0  

    //loop through the array of recommended video objects
    for index in recommended{

   //Create a button for each object 
       var myButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton

        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0.0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)

    //For the button action I call the handleTap function detailed below
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: "handleTap:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        myButton.tag = vidCount

    //The image for the button is pulled from a CDN. This code sets the image in the button.
        let curVal = index.thumbURL
        if let url = NSURL(string: curVal) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){

                myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(data:data), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            }
        }

    //add the button to the scroll view
        localScrollView.addSubview(myButton)

        let spacer:CGFloat = 10
        xPos+=buttonWidth + spacer
        scrollViewContent += buttonWidth + spacer

        localScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewContent, height: buttonHeight)
        vidCount += 1

    }


}


//function to handle the tap action
func handleTap(sender:UIButton){

    //Set the variable that will be passed to the next view controller
    curRecVid = recommended[sender.tag]

    //initiate the segue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSingle", sender: self)
    }

}

//prepare the data to be transferred to the next view controller
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toSingle") {
        var targetViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SingleViewController
        targetViewController.targetVid = curRecVid

    }
}
```

}

When I run the app in the simulator, it gets to the self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSingle", sender: self) call and then terminates to the following uncaught exception: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd468c8ddc0'

Any assistance in helping to track down the cause of this exception would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem isn't from this controller it is the destination view controller of that segue, so you might want to check it's code again.

Comment: you have to check the segue name again

Comment: I'm not currently seeing any errors in the target View Controller. Right now it's pretty stripped down. Just have a variable to catch the passed object, but I'm not doing anything with it yet because I haven't even gotten that far yet. I've even tried removing the passing data, and just tried to get the new view to open.

Comment: Can I ask why you are calling the segue on a different thread? As far as I know you call long tasks off the UI thread, but this task is a UI task.

Comment: Epic Defeater, you were correct. While all of the code looked correct in the target View Controller, I just wiped it out and created it again fresh. Bam, it works. I'm not sure what exactly was wrong with it, but regenerating the class for the target controller with the exact same content fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the class file for the target View Controller had some sort of problem. After a comment from Epic Defeater, I wiped out its swift file, re-generated it and put in the exact same code (literally, copy/paste) and that did the trick.